# Live application version is not reflecting in code

Tags: ios, app-store

We had iOS application whose version was 6.0. Now we have uploaded the build having version 6.1 and it is ready for sale from Today.

To fetch the app store version of our application we used "http://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?bundleId=com.app.sample" API.

My concern is this link is not giving currently Live app version due to which it is showing upgrade application. We checked it programmatically it is giving 6.0 version and if we hit the URL in browser it is giving correct version

Please assist. Does it take time to reflect the version?

Answer (score 1):

Updates can take up to 48hrs (official Apple guidance) to get correctly shown up on the Store. Developer experience shows that this can even be worse (up to 3-4 days)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After some time it gets reflected.